# mysql sequelize.js how to link two tables

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

This is my use case.

1. I have two tables **audits** and **user**
2. Whatever the user has done to the system is recorded in the **audits** table.
3. It means **user has many** audit records.

If I do

> Audits.belongsTo(User)

User model's primary key will be added to the Audits model as the foreign key.

But that foreign key value will be repeated  **since User has many Audits**.

For that reason do I need to add some relationship to the **User** model?

Answer (score 0):

> But that foreign key value will be repeated since User has many
>   Audits.

**That is how it should work** , There is nothing wrong in it , that's the standard way of RDBMS.

```
Audits.belongsTo(User)
```

**So go ahead.**